# Vb.net upload image - user accounts?

Tags: vb.net

Ok so at the moment I have a screenshot tool in vb.net, it uploads images directly to the site via FTP when screenshot taken..

However I am wanting to add 'user accounts' so like the users can store images they've upload and see history etc..what would the best way to go about this?

Basically I want; to go from uploading directly to FTP server and for users to have their own accounts where image get stored, which they'd be able To login via the program

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really broad, and not answerable in this format. There is no way to answer this definitively.

Comment: I was thinking about checking username and password via text based or MySQL database then it right it'll upload to a user directory or add link to a file named the username, really I'm after ideas how others would do it so I could get an idea and work from there